# Create a two dimensional array of different data types (Date and double)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make a program to do calculations of doubling time based on multiple readings at  different points in time.

I am using a Netbeans `JFrame` with a `JTextfield` and a `DateChooser` with an add button. I intend to add the values in the `JTextfield` and the `DateChooser` to a two dimensional array of the data type [Date,double] each time  the add button is clicked.

Once all the data is entered I have another button that then plots a graph based on these data points and calculates the doubling time and generates a report.

I am facing the following problems.

I will not know the number of elements I will have it can be 2 it can be 20 it will depend on the observations, I am unsure of how I can set this up in the context of a `JTextField`, `JButton` and `DateChooser`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I will not know the number of elements I will have it can be 2 it can
>   be 20 it will depend on the observations, I am unsure of how I can set
>   this up in the context of a JTextField, JButton and DateChooser

I wouldn't.  It would be eaiser to manage with a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

This way you won't need to care how many observations need to be made, they can simply keep adding new rows as they want.

I would also make a simple Object that contains the `Date` and `double` value, maybe called `Observation`, which can then simply be managed by the `JTable`'s model and if required, transferred to something like a `List` or array.

This links the `Date` and value together in a obvious manner which is not easily disconnected - IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Array, use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). That way you can use `List.add()` and you don't need to worry about how many elements are going to be in that list.

Elements in a list can be access similar to an array by using `List.get(index)` to get the objects or a more generic `for( element : List ) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have complex user type object with 2 fields and then have array of that object.